# How will Amazon's constellation differentiate itself from SpaceX's and OneWeb's?

Tags: spacex, communication, communication-satellite, satellite-constellation, business

The New York Times' [Amazon Satellites Add to Astronomers’ Worries About the Night Sky](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/08/10/science/amazon-project-kuiper.html) says:

> Much of the attention on these strings of satellites has been placed on the prolific launches of SpaceX and OneWeb, but the focus is now turning to Amazon. Last month, the Federal Communications Commission [approved a request](https://www.fcc.gov/document/fcc-authorizes-kuiper-satellite-constellation) by the online marketplace to launch its Project Kuiper constellation, which, like SpaceX’s Starlink and OneWeb’s network, aims to extend high-speed internet service to customers around the world, including to remote or underserved communities hobbled by a persistent digital divide.
>
> The Kuiper constellation would consist of **[3,236 satellites](https://blog.aboutamazon.com/company-news/amazon-receives-fcc-approval-for-project-kuiper-satellite-constellation)**. That’s more than the approximately 2,600 active satellites already orbiting Earth. While Amazon’s hardware is a long way from the launchpad, SpaceX has already deployed hundreds of satellites in its Starlink constellation, including 57 additional satellites that it launched on Friday. **It may expand it to 12,000, or more.** Facebook and Telesat could also get into the internet constellation business.

There are several more links in the original article but those I've linked to in the block quote are I think key to Amazon's plans.

The numbers are lower than for Starlink, so I wondered what it is that Amazon plans to do to differentiate itself from the presumably larger constellation that's had quite a head start. For example [Bezos' boots have *Gradatim Ferociter* written on them](https://twitter.com/JeffBezos/status/744554127728869376), the motto for Blue Origin. As far as Project Kuiper is concerned, how will they step ferociously on or over SpaceX and OneWeb and gain a foothold in space internet? How will it differentiate itself from them?

Comment: You will get free delivery.

Comment: The difference will be that Starlink exists.

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut I used future tense in the title. That's the point; if you want to do something similar to something that's happening now, you need to *differentiate* it.

Comment: Not a very easy question to answer given how secretive Blue Origin tends to be with their projects (at least as compared to SpaceX). Maybe they think they can offer better service, or they plan to target a different market. Or maybe they just think there's enough room for multiple competing LEO satellite internet constellations.