# How much delta-v have I used here? What's the "official" equation for delta-v from parametric thrust?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, delta-v, python

I took a break from Stack Exchange, jumped in my spacecar and flew the following squiggle:

$$a_x = \cos(10 \ t)$$
$$a_y = \sin(5 \ t)$$
$$a_z = \cos(2 \ t)$$

starting at `xyz = [-0.01, 0, -0.05]` and `v_xyz = [0, -0.2, 0]` with a total flight time of $2 \pi$.

When I got home I was told "Oh that was a lovely lissajous squiggle, but *how much delta-v did you put on the car?*"

I said "Oh, not much" and made a beeline to my computer to get back on Stack Exchange.

**Question:** How much delta-v DID I use?

1. If I have an acceleration vector (same as thrust vector; lets assume mass doesn't change) as a function of time $\mathbf{F}(t)$ what is the general integral expression for total delta-v should I use?
2. If someone looked up my trip in Horizons and got my state vectors $\mathbf{x}(t)$ and $\mathbf{v}(t)$ and had a numerical integrator and interpolator, what is the general integral expression for total delta-v *should they use?*

"bonus points" for including a Python script in your answer

[image: squiggle trajectory] [image: squiggle trajectory]

3D plot of position (returns to origin) and plots of velocity components

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ODEint

def deriv(X, t):
    x, v = X.reshape(2, -1)
    ax = np.cos(10*t)
    ay = np.sin(5*t)
    az = np.cos(2* t)
    return np.hstack((v, [ax, ay, az])) 

times = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1001)

X0 = np.hstack(([-0.01, 0, -0.05], [0, -0.2, 0]))

answer, info = ODEint(deriv, X0, times, full_output=True)

xyz, vxyz = answer.T.reshape(2, 3, -1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d', proj_type = 'ortho')
x, y, z = xyz
ax.plot(x, y, z)
ax.plot(x[:1], y[:1], z[:1], 'ok')
ax.plot(x[-1:], y[-1:], z[-1:], 'or')
plt.show()

for thing in vxyz:
    plt.plot(thing)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This feels more like code golf than a genuine space question... at best it's a math question about basic calculus.  Either way, I don't think it's a good fit here.  This is written like a homework assignment.  This is Q&A, not Mechanical Turk.

Comment: @J... as far as I know the concept of "delta-v" is specific to spaceflight. If you can show otherwise I would be happy to find out.

Comment: That's not the point.

Comment: That's exactly the point. "is written like a homework assignment" just means that it is *stylized.* After writing over 2001 questions here you have to mix it up a bit to stay fresh :-)

Comment: @J... When a question is too big or complicatged to fit into one SE question post, we break it up into smaller answerable pieces. I'm currently still uncomfortable with [this hand-waving answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48017/12102) using an unexplained and unsourced equation, so I first asked [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48033/12102) so that the equation could have a foundation. Next I made [this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BKDM.png) In order to start thinking about extracting post-launch delta-v for deep space spacecraft using its state vectors.

Comment: @J... Once we establish a basis for doing that, then we have to deal with real world gravity-gradient potentials. This all goes back to [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16644/12102) when I first started trying to differentiate propulsive maneuvers from state vectors. Maybe all together we can finally get an answer to [this old question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27746/12102), one of the items on my bucket list, along with [everting a sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/246851/96907).

Comment: You're trying to run before you can walk.  This question is still off topic.

Comment: Hardly, this steady, methodical approach to problem solving is "[examplary](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/370717/217285)" of [Gradatim Ferociter](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46157/12102), and "How to calculate delta-v?" has always been *squarely on-topic* in Space Exploration SE and always will be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As $\Delta v$ is just change in velocity, we can just integrate the norm of the acceleration function over time:

$$\Delta v = \int|\mathbf{a}(t)| dt$$

You're out of luck getting a closed form of that integral though.

As far as analytical solutions goes, we can note that at $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$, all of $a_x$, $a_y$ and $a_z$ are maxed out, and hence $\Delta v < 2\pi\sqrt{3}$.

Similarly, the acceleration at all times is going to be greater than or equal to one of the components, and since they are trigonometric functions, their integrals are trivial.

$$4 < \Delta v < 2\pi\sqrt{3}$$

I can't see that there's much more to it from here than just putting the acceleration function into a numerical integrator. It's a smooth curve, so they are good at this.

```
Integral(sqrt(cos(10*x)^2 + sin(5*x)^2 + cos(2*x)^2),0,2*pi)
-> 7.5279
```

Or, by the definition of acceleration, if what you have is velocity data:

$$\Delta v = \int\left|\frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt}\right| dt$$

Which if you have tabular data and don't bother with interpolation, is simply:

$$\Delta v =\sum |d\mathbf{v}|$$

Which is just summing up all the velocity differences between the discrete data points.

Comment: Great answer. The analytic solution of the line integral seems to be an elliptic integral, is that right?